# How hide or change tooltip text in mat-paginator?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanna change/hide tool-tip - next and previous page in mat-paginator.

```
<mat-paginator [length]="lenght" [pageSize]="size">
</mat-paginator>
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your component class, you need to get a reference to `MatPaginator` using `@ViewChild`. From that reference, you get access to the [MatPaginatorIntl](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#MatPaginatorIntl) service that lets you changes the different labels.

For example, the following example would hide tool-tips for previous and next buttons.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, undefined) paginator: MatPaginator;

ngOnInit() {
    const paginatorIntl = this.paginator._intl;
    paginatorIntl.nextPageLabel = '';
    paginatorIntl.previousPageLabel = '';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you dont need text, fastest way is to hide element with css :)

```css
mat-tooltip-component {
  display: none !important;
}
```